# How can $a\geq 2b\log b$ and $b\geq 9$ imply $a/\log a\geq b$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

The following slick argument is used in a paper and I don't know how to prove it:

> If $a\geq 2b\log b$ and $b\geq 9$, then 
>   $$
> \frac{a}{\log a}\geq b.\tag{*}$$

It seems that one needs a upper bound for $\log a$, which is the part I don't know.

Could anyone prove (*)?

Comment: $\log$ is the natural logarithm?

Comment: @JonasMeyer : I think so, assuming that is where $b\geq9$ is used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $b \ge 9$ and $a \ge 2 b \log(b)$, $a \ge 18 \log(9) > 18$.

If $a \ge 2 b \log(b)$ and $b > a/\log(a)$, we'd have
$b \log(a) > a \ge 2 b \log(b)$, so $\log(a) > 2 \log(b)$, and thus
$a > b^2$. But
$ a/\log(a) > a^{1/2}$ for $a > 3$, so now

$$b > \frac{a}{\log(a)} > a^{1/2} > b$$

Contradiction!

Comment: What does $`18$ mean?

Comment: Slip of the finger.  Edited.